# How to forward formatting information from std::format

Tags: c++, format, c++20, stdformat

I am trying to use c++20's std::format on msvc.
When I try to define a format for a custom type Person, I hope to be able to use the external `std::format("{:x}{:*^10}", person)` in `"{:x}{:*^10}"` is forwarded to `std::formatter<Person>::fomat` and used directly in `std::formatter<Person>::fomat`
for example:

```cpp
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

class Person {
public:
    int age;
    std::string name;

};

template <>
struct std::formatter<Person> : std::formatter<std::string> {
    template <typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const Person& p, FormatContext& ctx) {
        // I hope that the "forwarded format" here is "{:x}{:*^10}" in the format information of ::std::format in main. \
          This code is of course not runnable. I want to know How can I use an external format in formatter<Person>::foaramt like this
        return format_to(ctx.out(),"forwarded format",p.age,p.name);
    }
};

int main() {
    Person person{ 30,"John Doe" };
    std::cout << std::format("{:x}{:*^10}", p) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

I hope to be able to use the forwarded formatting information "{:x}{:*^10}" directly in std::formatter::format,
Instead of changing `std::foramt("{:x}{:*^10}",person)` to `std::format("{:x}{:*^10}",person.age,person.name)`

Comment: First of all thanks for pointing out my mistake, I have corrected the first mistake.
I have another problem that I can't get ``{:x, *^10}`` in std::format("{:x, *^10}") in std::formatter<Person>::fotmat , how should I get it.@康桓瑋

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a `string_view` variable in `std::formatter<Person>` to store formatting information.

Then, calculate the format string for members in the `parse()` function and assign it to this variable, and use it in the `format()` function.

(For simplicity, some compile-time checks inside the `parse` function are omitted)

```
template <>
struct std::formatter<Person> {
  std::string_view fmt_str; // formatting information

  template<typename ParseContext>
  constexpr auto parse(ParseContext& ctx) {
    auto begin = ctx.begin();                       // ctx is "x}{:*^10}"
    auto it = std::formatter<int>{}.parse(ctx);     // now, it point to "}{:*^10}"
    it = std::ranges::find(it + 1, ctx.end(), ':'); // now, it point to ":*^10}"
    ctx.advance_to(it + 1);                         // now, ctx is "*^10}"
    it = std::formatter<std::string>{}.parse(ctx);  // now, it point to "}"
    fmt_str = {begin - 2, it + 1};                  // now fmt_str is "{:x}{:*^10}"
    return it;
  }

  template <typename FormatContext>
  auto format(const Person& p, FormatContext& ctx) const {
    return std::vformat_to(ctx.out(), fmt_str, std::make_format_args(p.age, p.name));
  }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vr78E3fYh)

Comment: Thank you very much, this demo is exactly what I described,
I got an error when running on msvc2022, ``"C7595 "std::_Basic_format_string<char,Person &>::_Basic_format_string": call to immediate function is not a constant expression"``, this error appears on line 35 and line 36 of the demo ,
Why is this? Is it because msvc's support for std::format is not perfect?

Comment: @NeC I can't reproduce your problem, the above code also compiles fine in MSVC, [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/P5qjrE93P)

Comment: I use the 17.4.5 version of vs 2022, and the msvc version is v143. This problem does exist. I don’t know what version corresponds to the msvc 19.30 in the demo.
At the same time, I decided not to worry about this problem. This is most likely my compiler version There is a problem, thank you very much for your help.@康桓瑋

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad goal:

```cpp
std::format("{:x}{:*^10}", p)
```

This is an expression that looks like it's formatting two arguments, but is actually formatting only one. Sure, you can make it work, but... this is incredibly confusing.

A better goal would instead to make this work:

```cpp
std::format("{:{x}{*^10}}", p)
```

That is, you only have *one* replacement-field, whose format-spec is `{x}{*^10}`. This is more consistent with the way the rest of the library works.

And then we can do all the things we need to do more directly, using `formatter<int>` and `formatter<string>`:

```cpp
template <>
struct std::formatter<Person> {
  std::formatter<int> age;
  std::formatter<std::string> name;


  template<typename ParseContext>
  constexpr auto parse(ParseContext& ctx) {
    auto it = ctx.begin();
    if (it == ctx.end() || *it == '}') {
      if (age.parse(ctx) != it || name.parse(ctx) != it) {
        throw std::format_error("bad");
      }
      return it;
    }

    if (*it != '{') throw std::format_error("bad");
    ctx.advance_to(it + 1);
    it = age.parse(ctx);
    if (it == ctx.end() || *it != '}') throw std::format_error("bad");
    ++it;
    if (it == ctx.end() || *it != '{') throw std::format_error("bad");
    ctx.advance_to(it + 1);
    it = name.parse(ctx);
    if (it == ctx.end() || *it != '}') throw std::format_error("bad");
    return it + 1;
  }

  template <typename FormatContext>
  auto format(const Person& p, FormatContext& ctx) const {
    ctx.advance_to(age.format(p.age, ctx));
    ctx.advance_to(name.format(p.name, ctx));
    return ctx.out();
  }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vE7KnP77q).

This is still using the underlying `int` and `string` formatters with their respective specs and ensuring that works properly, in an efficient way (i.e. they are only parsed one time, not twice).

See my [CppCon 2022 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EQELdyecZlU) for more examples of doing this sort of thing, also in more depth (the talk has an example of formatting `std::tuple<Ts...>`, of which this is a special case).

Comment: I'm stuck with a format like `{:{x}      {*^10}}` (note the space here), if so, how do we format the space in the `format()`? Do we still need to define an additional variable inside the `formatter` to hold the random text between the two replacement fields?

Comment: @康桓瑋 Yeah, you can do that. Between the `}` of the first one and the `{` of the second one, instead of just mandating that those are consecutive (like I'm doing) you could stash the whole content as a `string_view` member and then format that.

Comment: @康桓瑋 [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bj733ddzP)

Comment: Why did you use a template parameter for `parse`?! Is the type any other than `basic_format_parse_context<char>`?! Even if the `formatter` specialization used the `CharT`argument, shouldn't that `CharT` be the argument for `basic_format_parse_context`?!

Comment: @Barry In the OP's comment (which has been deleted), he also wants to use format strings such as `{: My age is {x}, and my name is  {*^10}}`, so we may need to use two `string_view`s to hold those random contents, which also makes the `parse()` much more complicated. Thanks for the demo showing a possible solution anyway.

Comment: @Red.Wave Why are you asking every question with exclamation points!!!?!!!?!!!!?!

Comment: @康桓瑋 You can do `"My age is {:{x}, and my name is {*^10}}"`. The leading string can just be printed, it doesn't need to be part of the format spec. This is what chrono does basically with all of the `%Y`, `%H`, etc. stuff... except that it doesn't let you use specifiers for each field, you just ask for fields.

Comment: @Barry consider it a parsing error but I am seriously curious. Can you enlite me please? Is there any specific reason or implementation complexity involved, or just out of habit for not having to remember the exact type?

Comment: @Red.Wave Yeah so it's always `std::format_parse_context` here, but then the format context itself needs to be a template. I usually just write `auto&` everywhere since I'm never looking at the type.

Comment: @Barry So that's the alias for `char` and I guess there are `wformat_parse_context` et al too. Thanks, but IMHO in a public talk or documentation a little bit of more precision can be beneficial.

Comment: @Barry I need to request some format features. How can I get a relevant contact please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252112/discussion-between-red-wave-and-barry).